# Stack, Frame, Global Pointer and ELF files

Tags: stack, global, frame, elf

How do I determine where the stack, global, and frame pointers are in my ELF file?

Comment: stack is created when your program is running.  it is not in the elf file.

global is the .data .sdata section in elf, and the .bss .sbss for zero'd global

Answer (score 0):

Stack is setup when process or thread run. function or routine body contain codes that how to be called or call other subroutines, they indicate how much stack space will be used.

Frame pointer is related to stack frame which are dynamic updated.

Global variables are in data section in ELF file.

Hope this can help you.